# Online service for publicly sharing photos via Android?

Tags: java, android, social-networking, sharing

I'm working on an Android app where I want users to be able to take photographs, submit the photos online to a central public repository and then other users can browse all submitted photos. Other features that would be nice would be the ability to vote on the best photos and for users to be able to submit photos anonymously as well as submitting via an account that assigns them an identity. Can anyone recommend an existing online service that can support most of these features?

The only thing I can think of is flickr, although I can't see an Android specific API and it looks as if it would require that the user sign-up before submitting photos (which isn't great because most users hate signing up to things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Android PhotoStream](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/09/android-photostream.html) sample application. Everything is explained there

Comment: Wow, that Flickr for Android code looks very useful. However, do you know if Flickr let's users upload photos anonymously?

Comment: I don't know - never used Flickr

Answer (score 0):

Nice app..

Instead of publishing the photo to a website of your choice, why can't you launch a set of applications that handles photos/publishes photos?

As suggested by barmaley, Android PhotoStream is one of them.

A sample coding for opening a text Editor is here..

```
public void share(String subject,String text) {
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);

 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share)));
}
```

Refer here for more about setting MIME Types for Intents:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: This isn't ideal as the user has to download another app to use my app. The online service I'll be using is a bigger concern really as they all appear to require the user login first which creates a barrier to use the upload feature.

Comment: All users by default have atleast one photo sharing app already. I have 2 installed in my devices. You should go by user's choice. This is the ideal way. This is how android is supposed to work. If no such app exists then you can load your code for doing the sharing.

Comment: Why is this ideal? I would like the user to be able to upload photos to share with other users of my app with one tap to create a seamless user experience (note I'm not asking how to share with any service, just one that is tied to my app). Making the user launch another app (which could itself have a bad interface) and, more than likely, having to install an extra app is going to be a terrible user experience.